# Picasso load image into GifImageView (android-gif-drawable library)

Tags: android, animated-gif, picasso

I am using the [android-gif-drawable](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable) library to display an animated gif in an Android view. This library can load a file from an input stream, byte array, byte buffer, or from a locally stored file. I am looking for a way to use Picasso to download the gif and pass it to the library to load into the GifImageView. Unfortunately, once the downloaded image is converted to a Bitmap, it just becomes a single frame. I'm thinking a custom request handler might be able to hand off an input stream for the GifImageView to load, but I cannot seem to figure out the syntax to do this. Does anyone have pointers or thoughts on doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you haven't figured it out yet, you can use the library [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion). I was facing the same problem a few days ago, and it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was trying to figure out a way to keep the method count in my app low for Android 2.3 compatibility (Picasso has a very low method count). I ended up going back to using Glide for animated gifs and reducing the method count be removing some other libraries that were in use.

Comment: Further to @taitasciore's comment, here's the code to make it work:    GifImageView imageView = ((GifImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.explainer_gif));
    String url = "<your url>";
    Ion.with(imageView)
        .load(url);